# How to reverse engineer MySQL database tables one-by-one onto an ERD using WorkBench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, erd

I have a database containing hundreds of tables, and I want to create an **ERD** out of that using **MySql Workbench's reverse engineer** feature.

But reverse engineering such amount of objects at once is beyond workbench's capabilities, so I'm planning to do it one-by-one, I already have these five tables that I know are related to each other and reversed engineered it successfully, and now I have an **ERD** of them. But what I want to do is add more tables as I see fit from the same database onto the generated **ERD** from reverse engineering those five tables before.

I know I can probably do this by generating a new **ERD** each time I want to add another table to those five tables. But is there a work-around for this that I don't have to reverse engineer each time I want to add a new table that I thinks is related to those five tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reverse engineering into a new model and save that. Open your main model and choose File -> Include Model to include your other model.

Btw: there are certainly limits for content in a model (and even more: on a single diagram), but at least you should be able to reverse engineer at least 200 objects at once.

Answer (score -1):

Download this -> http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ and then once you've set it up you simply click the database tab and then the reverse engineer section!